# JSP JSTL does not write HTML

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have an assignment for a one web page to show a table based on a selected date range (week, month or quarter) and a selected date. The data is from a read-only JSON file. A `<select>` control is filled with start dates using jQuery (not my preference but it works). Selecting a start date should cause a set of records to be chosen to be displayed in the `<table>` using JSTL `<c:out>`. I observe the correct data being requested by `<c:forEach>` from EventInfo#getDate() but no HTML code is written. I also failed to get JSTL to write `<option>` for the `<select>` control or even a `<label>`.

I am not sure what else to check to get this to work, such as pom.xml, file locations.

The java servlet and class files are in src/edjusterJsp/.
HomePage.jsp and actions.js are in WebContent/.
The data files is in WebContent/WEB-INF/.
Development is done in Eclipse/Luna on Windows Vista using Chrome to view.

HomePage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Joe Brown's Assignment for e|djuster</title>
<style>
    .picklab
    {
        width: 10em;
    }
    .pickcontrol
    {
        width: 8em;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="actions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Joe Brown's Data Viewer</h1>
    <c:set var="greeting" value="Hello World" />
    <c:out value="${greeting}" />
    <form action="JoeabServlet" method="post">
        <label class="picklab">Period</label>
        <select id="periodtype" class="pickcontrol pickler" required>
            <option>select</option>
            <option value="ptweek">Week</option>
            <option value="ptmonth">Month</option>
            <option value="ptquarter">Quarter</option>
        </select><br>
        <label class="picklab">Start Date</label>
        <select id="periodrange" class="pickcontrol pickled">
            <option>Please select parent</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update Summary" />
        <table id="summaryz">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Summary</th>
                    <th>Metric</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>One</td>
                    <td>Two</td>
                    <td>Three</td>
                    <td>Four</td>
                 </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${eventinfos}" var="evinfo">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${evinfo.getEventDate()}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${evinfo.getEventType()}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${evinfo.getEventSummary()}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${evinfo.getEventSize()}" /></td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JoeabServlet.java (portion)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String fillid = request.getParameter("fillid"); // ID of child DD to fill options for.
    String periodsize = request.getParameter("periodsize");
    String val = request.getParameter("val"); // Value of parent DD to find associated child DD options for.
    System.out.println("doGet() fillid: " + fillid + "  periodsize: " + periodsize + "   val: " + val);

    String jsonText = "invalid";
    if (0 == fillid.compareTo("periodrange"))
    {
        // Generate date options for a period type
        List<String> dates = getPeriodRanges(val);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JSONValue.writeJSONString(dates, sw);
        jsonText = sw.toString();

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(jsonText);
    }
    else if (0 == fillid.compareTo("summaryz"))
    {
        // Generate summary data for the table
        System.out.println("doGet() matched summaryz");
        List<EventInfo> evInfos = getEventInfos(periodsize, val);
        request.setAttribute("eventinfos", evInfos);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/HomePage.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

actions.js (portion)

```
function fillSummaries(tableToFillID, ddTypeId, callingElement)
{
    var tableau = $("#" + tableToFillID);
    var dd = $('#' + ddTypeId);
    console.debug("selected: " + $(callingElement).children(':selected'));
    console.debug("selected text: " + $(callingElement).children(':selected').text());
    sdate = $(callingElement).children(':selected').text();
    console.debug("sdate : " + sdate);
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/edjusterJsp/JoeabServlet?fillid=' + tableToFillID + '&periodsize=' + dd.val() + '&val=' + sdate);
}
```

EventInfo.java (portion)

```
public class EventInfo
{
    protected String event_date;
    protected String event_type;
    protected String event_summary;
    protected String event_size;

    public String getEventDate()
    {
        System.out.println("get event_date" + event_date); 
        return event_date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Who calls fillSummaries? What will be done with the result of getJSON()?

Comment: fillSummaries is attached to <select id="periodrange" class="pickcontrol pickled"> on startup. It correctly fills the control with dates.

Comment: getJSON sends a message to the servlet to fill the table. The message is received but the table filling fails.

Comment: jQuery getJSON looks like `jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )` There is a success parameter which takes a function that will be called, when all data is arrived.

Comment: I removed it because it was just clearing <table> contents. My problem was that I want to fill the <table><tbody> using JSTL. It showed that it read the data from the EventInfo instances but no <tr>s were written. I also failed to get JSTL to write <option> or <label>.